# Defining a contact form

Tags: differential-geometry, contact-topology

I am trying to understand contact structures. To this end, as an exercise, I intend to define a contact form on $S^3$. Here is what I have so far:

Since $S^3$ is in $\mathbb R^4$ one can specify a point on $S^3$ by a $4$-tuple $(x,y,z,w)$. If one endows $S^3$ with stereographic coordinate charts one obtain coordinates as follows: $({2X\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1}, {2Y\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1}, {2Z\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1}, {X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 - 1\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1})$ where $(X,Y,Z)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^3$.

The [standard contact structure on $S^3$](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Contact_manifold#The_standard_contact_structure_on_S2n.2B1) is given by  $xdz - z dx + y dw - w dy$.

My question is:

> Does $xdz - z dx + y dw - w dy$ mean the contact structure is
>   ${2X\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1}d{2Z\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1} - \dots$
>   and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you use the stereographic projection then it is the form you indicated.

To be precise, $\alpha = x dz - zdx + y dw - wdy$ is a one form on $\mathbb R^4$. So the contact structure on $\mathbb S^3$ is really $\iota^* \alpha$, where $\iota : \mathbb S^3 \to \mathbb R^4$ is the inclusion.

Comment: Hm... This suggests I can take any $1$-form in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ and then the inclusion of it will make it a contact form on $S^{2n-1}$?

Comment: Is the inclusion map $i: S^3 \to \mathbb R^4$ the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y,z,0)$?

Comment: No, wait, it's $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y,z)$, right? But isn't then $\iota^\ast \alpha = \alpha$ because $\iota^\ast$ is the identity?

Comment: $\mathbb S^{2n-1}$ itself is a manifold, and $i$ is really the set inclusion mapping @self-learner

Comment: But $\iota6\ast \alpha = \alpha$, right? Because $\iota^\ast$ is the identity.

Comment: $\alpha$ is not a one form on $\mathbb S^{3}$. It's a one form on $\mathbb R^4$. there is a difference between $\iota^*\alpha$ and $\alpha$. For example, if $\beta = x dx + ydx + zdz +wdw $ on $\mathbb R^4$, then $\iota^*\beta$ is actually zero. The identity $\iota^* \alpha = \alpha$ just don't make sense since they are different object. @self-learner

Comment: I believe to have found an easier way: to use the contact structure on some $\mathbb R^n$ on a sphere by moving up the dimension. For example, on $\mathbb R^5$ the standard contact structure is $$ \alpha = dz + \sum_{j=1}^2 x_j dy_j$$
Now since $S^3$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^5$ we can use this structure as is on $S^3$. This works, right? Or am I missing something?